# How to send each node of an XML file to a new line when i copy it to a richTextbox?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I use the following code to copy the content of an XML file into a richTextox

`XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();

  xdoc.Load(filename);

  richTextBox1.Text = xdoc.InnerText;`

but the result is a continuous string, for example

`<node1>...</node1><node2>...</node2><node3>...</node3>`

So how could I send each element to an new line?
In order to have the same result but vertically.
Is it possible to do it the way that I copy the content to the richTexbox?

Comment: Can you use XmlTextWriter with `w.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;`?

Comment: "So how could I send each node to an new line?" I assume you mean "each element"? Otherwise, an element with an attribute and text content would require at least three lines: one for the element node, one for the attribute node, and one for the text node.

Comment: correct! I meant each element. But no matter how much I try to use XmlTextWriter I can't, I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: You could post the code you tried with XmlTextWriter, along with the results it produces, and we might be able to help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for. Been a while since I worked on C#

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(filename);
XmlNode root = xdoc.DocumentElement;

    //Display the contents of the child nodes.
    if (root.HasChildNodes)
    {
      for (int i=0; i<root.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
      {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(root.ChildNodes[i].InnerText+"\n");
      }
    }
```

Comment: This will put each child (of root) node on a single line, but will not put a newline between grandchild elements. I thought the OP wanted a newline after every descendant element... he says "each node", which I interpret to mean "each element".

Comment: I see. He didn't want the contents of each node? So he wants to have a line after the elements. Do i delete my answer then?

Comment: I think he does want the contents of each element, but he also wants a newline after each element (i.e. after the close tag). Again, my interpretation. You could update your answer to recursively descend into each child element and put a newline after each descendant element. Or you could leave your answer as-is and see if it's sufficient for the OP's purpose.

Comment: ans u commented would be sufficient for that functionality!

Comment: I will leave it as-is and make changes as he wants.

Comment: I'm trying to make it work. And the code seams reasonable but when I use it as-is I get no results in the textbox.

Comment: It's printing out the contents for me. do you have any uncommented code after the loop?

Comment: u can either use xdoc.Load/xdoc.LoadXml could be a simple parsing error.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Only that it need one modification. Instead of "FirstChild" I used "DocumentElement". I guess it didn't work in the first place because I don't have a second child in my XML. I'm not sure maybe it's because of something else. Anyway I'm making the modification in your answer and I'm marking it as correct. Thank you so much!

Comment: I am glad it worked out. I run through a couple of xml it went through fine. feel free to edit as you wish